# Check if any element in list exists in a string

Tags: python

Here is an example that I would like to print **TRUE** since `Drug` is in the string. If `disease` was in the string, I would like it to print **TRUE** as well. For all other cases I want to print **FALSE**

```
mystring =  "Drug   CID006338583    AC1O3UYX    Stitch  1.515E-3    1.000E0 4.989E-2    5.235E-1    4   63  PTGES,SLC15A1,KLK8,IL7R"
check_if_in_mystring = ['Drug', 'Disease']

if check_if_in_mystring in mystring:
    print("TRUE")
else:
    print("FALSE")
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me in understanding the question better? I am a little confused as to do you want True if both Drug and Disease are in the string or do you want True if either one of them is present?

Answer (score 5):

Your example is correct you can use `'in'` operator on string, just add a loop on `'check_if_in_mystring'` to iterate over every element you want to check, like below example.

```
mystring =  "Drug   CID006338583    AC1O3UYX    Stitch  1.515E-3    1.000E0 4.989E-2    5.235E-1    4   63  PTGES,SLC15A1,KLK8,IL7R"
check_if_in_mystring = ['Drug', 'Disease']

for element in check_if_in_mystring:
    if element in mystring:
        print("TRUE for {}".format(element))
    else:
        print("FALSE for {}".format(element))
```

output:

```
TRUE for Drug
FALSE for Disease
```

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will detect if any one of `check_if_in_mystring` is in `mystring`:

```
any(word in mystring for word in check_if_in_mystring)
```

For the exact behavior from the question:

```
print(str(any(word in mystring for word in check_if_in_mystring)).upper())
```

Comment: short, simple, does what's requested - why downvote sth like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> my_string = "Drug   CID006338583    AC1O3UYX    Stitch  
1.515E-3    1.000E0 4.989E-2    5.235E-1    4   63  PTGES,SLC15A1,KLK8,IL7R"

>>> print("TRUE" if "Drug" in my_string or "Disease" in my_string else 
"FALSE")

TRUE

>>> my_string = "Some other random string"

>>> print("TRUE" if "Drug" in my_string or "Disease" in my_string else 
"FALSE")

FALSE

>>> my_string = "Has the word Disease"

>>> print("TRUE" if "Drug" in my_string or "Disease" in my_string else 
"FALSE")

TRUE
```

strings support the `in` operator, so you can just check if `Drug` or `Disease` are in `my_string`.

Answer (score 0):

converting string to list and checking in list can be one solution,
as solved below.

```
mystring =  "Drug   CID006338583    AC1O3UYX    Stitch  1.515E-3    1.000E0 4.989E-2    5.235E-1    4   63  PTGES,SLC15A1,KLK8,IL7R"
check_if_in_mystring = ['Drug', 'Disease']
mystring1 = mystring.split() #convertin string to list, seprated by white space
for item in check_if_in_mystring:
    if item in mystring1:
        print(item)
        print("TRUE")
    else:
        print(item)
        print("FALSE")
```

Output:printing work and its presence in mystring

```
Drug
TRUE
Disease
FALSE
```

Comment: There's no need to split `mystring` into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Alex Taylor's on the right track, but the `any` clause can be greatly simplified:

```
>>> mystring =  "Drug   CID006338583    AC1O3UYX    Stitch  1.515E-3    1.000E0 4.989E-2    5.235E-1    4   63  PTGES,SLC15A1,KLK8,IL7R"
>>> check_if_in_mystring = ['Drug', 'Disease']
>>> any(word in mystring for word in check_if_in_mystring)
True
>>> mystring =  "Poodle   CID006338583    AC1O3UYX    Stitch  1.515E-3    1.000E0 4.989E-2    5.235E-1    4   63  PTGES,SLC15A1,KLK8,IL7R"
>>> any(word in mystring for word in check_if_in_mystring)
False
```

These approaches loop across the list of words in `check_if_in_mystring`, and `any(...)` returns `True` as soon as the first `word in mystring` expression is `True`. If the `for word in check_if_in_mystring` loop finishes without finding a `True` value, then `any(...)` returns False.

Comment: I agree this is a better approach. I've changed my answer and made it more specific to the question asked too.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use:

```
mystring.contains(anotherstring)
```